# error on cassandra installation on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cassandra, installation, ubuntu-14.04, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to install cassandra 3.11.4 on ubuntu 14.04.
When I run the install command, the following error is returned

> dpkg-deb: error: archive
>   '/var/cache/apt/archives/cassandra_3.11.4_all.deb' has premature
>   member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
>
> dpkg: error processing archive
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/cassandra_3.11.4_all.deb (--unpack): 
>   subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
>
> Errors were encountered while processing: 
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/cassandra_3.11.4_all.deb E: Sub-process
>   /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065231/dpkg-deb-error-archive-has-premature-member-control-tar-xz-before-contr?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue once.
Please follow these steps and before installing Cassandra please make sure installation of JDK & python2.7.

**Step 1: Install OpenJDK JRE 8**
Apache Cassandra requires the latest release of Java 8. For that you can choose to install the latest release of OpenJDK JRE 1.8 as below:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre -y
```

Having OpenJDK JRE 1.8 installed, you can confirm the installation result:

```
java -version
```

The output will be similar to the following:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Optionally, you can create the JAVA_HOME environment variable as follows:

```
echo "JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
source /etc/profile
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

**Step 2: Install Python 2.7, if it's missing on your system**
Apache Cassandra requires Python 2.7 rather than Python 3. If you operate Apache Cassandra in a Python 3 environment, you may have trouble launching the 
 the shell of Apache Cassandra.
First, determine the existence and version of Python on your machine:

```
python -V
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the output can be slightly confusing:

```
The program 'python' can be found in the following packages:
* python-minimal
* python3
Ask your administrator to install one of them
```

That actually means you need to install Python 2.7 by yourself:

```
sudo apt install python -y
```

Re-run the 
 command and the output will become:

```
Python 2.7.12
```

**Step 3: Install the latest stable release of Apache Cassandra**
Create the Apache Cassandra 3.11.x apt repo:

```
echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
curl https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS | sudo apt-key add -
```

If you encounter a GPG public key error, run the following commands to add the mentioned Apache Cassandra public key, which is 
 in this case:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key A278B781FE4B2BDA
sudo apt-get update
```

Use the newly added repo to install Apache Cassandra:

```
sudo apt-get install cassandra
```

**Step 4: Test the installation of Apache Cassandra**
Start the Apache Cassandra daemon:

```
sudo service cassandra start
```

If you want to make Apache Cassandra automatically start at system boot, run the following command:

```
sudo update-rc.d cassandra defaults
```

Next, use the nodetool
 program to show the status of Apache Cassandra on the current node:

```
nodetool status
```

The output will resemble the following:

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  102.66 KiB  256          100.0%            23916cfd-892d-4898-857c-aff9efe2354a  rack1
```

You can use the 
 shell to interact with Apache Cassandra:

> cqlsh localhost

The output will be similar to the following:
For now, just type 
 and then press ENTER to quit the cqlsh shell.
If you want to stop Apache Cassandra, execute the following command:

```
sudo service cassandra stop
```